# handle collapsing html table by click on button and not by click to row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and already set up the collapsing table below with jquery. This already works. I can expand or collapse the complete table or expand and collapse columns by clicking on the row.

But this also changes the view by setting options like BRS or set (see HTML).

What I want is so control all this by the button "+" in the first column (see HTML).

Maybe it's simple maybe not. Can someone help me?

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each( function() { // hide all at start
                if(!($(this).is('.expandable')))
                $(this).hide();
        });
        $('.expandable').click(function () {   // toggle single by click
                $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
                        if($(this).is('.expandable')) {
                                return false; }
                        $(this).toggle();
                });
        });
 $('#expand_all').click(function() {   // show all
  $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
   if(!($(this).is('.expandable')))
  $(this).show();
  });
 });
 $('#collaps_all').click(function() {   // hide all
  $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
   if(!($(this).is('.expandable')))
  $(this).hide();
  });
 })
});
</script><title>ConfigPage for CAN on RestbusSimulationStation</title>
<body>
<h2>RSS</h2>
<button style="font-size:20px" id="expand_all">expand all</button><button style="font-size:20px" id="collaps_all">collaps all</button>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#fb9d00">
<th></th>
<th>FRAMES</th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>DLC</th>
<th>BRS</th>
<th>CYCLE/s</th>
<th>SET</th>
<th>SIGNALS</th>
<th>POS</th>
<th>Bits</th>
<th>select:</th>
<th>comput method</th>
<th>enum</th>
</tr>

<tr class="expandable">
<td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
<td><strong>EOCM_CAN8_MSG01</strong></td>
<td>37</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="brs">
</td>
<td>0.01</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="frame" checked>
</td>
<tr><td><td><td><td><td><td>
<td><span title="Host Vehicle Path Curvature
">IHstVhPthCrvt</span></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="value" required="required" value="0" min="0" max="32767"><td></td>
<td><input type="number" name="enum" min="0" style="width: 3em;"></td>
</td>
</td></td></td></td></td></td></tr>

<tr class="expandable">
<td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
<td><strong>EOCM_CAN8_MSG01</strong></td>
<td>37</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="brs">
</td>
<td>0.01</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="frame" checked>
</td>
<tr><td><td><td><td><td><td>
<td><span title="Host Vehicle Path Curvature
">IHstVhPthCrvt</span></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="value" required="required" value="0" min="0" max="32767"><td></td>
<td><input type="number" name="enum" min="0" style="width: 3em;"></td>
</td>
</td></td></td></td></td></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this approach.
Instead of attaching `click` handler to `<tr>`; we are attaching it to the `button` like `$('.expandable input[type=button]').click`. Apart from that rest of the code is almost as it is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each(function() { // hide all at start
      if (!($(this).is('.expandable')))
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('.expandable input[type=button]').click(function() { // toggle single by click
      var trElem = $(this).closest("tr");
      trElem.nextAll('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.expandable')) {
          return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle();
      });
    });
    $('#expand_all').click(function() { // show all
      $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each(function() {
        if (!($(this).is('.expandable')))
          $(this).show();
      });
    });
    $('#collaps_all').click(function() { // hide all
      $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each(function() {
        if (!($(this).is('.expandable')))
          $(this).hide();
      });
    })
  });
</script>
<title>ConfigPage for CAN on RestbusSimulationStation</title>

<body>
  <h2>RSS</h2>
  <button style="font-size:20px" id="expand_all">expand all</button>
  <button style="font-size:20px" id="collaps_all">collaps all</button>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#fb9d00">
      <th></th>
      <th>FRAMES</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>DLC</th>
      <th>BRS</th>
      <th>CYCLE/s</th>
      <th>SET</th>
      <th>SIGNALS</th>
      <th>POS</th>
      <th>Bits</th>
      <th>select:</th>
      <th>comput method</th>
      <th>enum</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="expandable">
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="+">
      </td>
      <td><strong>EOCM_CAN8_MSG01</strong>
      </td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="brs">
      </td>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="frame" checked>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <td>
            <td>
              <td>
                <td>
                  <td>
                    <td><span title="Host Vehicle Path Curvature
">IHstVhPthCrvt</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="number" name="value" required="required" value="0" min="0" max="32767">
                      <td></td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="number" name="enum" min="0" style="width: 3em;">
                      </td>
                    </td>
                  </td>
                </td>
              </td>
            </td>
          </td>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="expandable">
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="+">
        </td>
        <td><strong>EOCM_CAN8_MSG01</strong>
        </td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="brs">
        </td>
        <td>0.01</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="frame" checked>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <td>
              <td>
                <td>
                  <td>
                    <td>
                      <td><span title="Host Vehicle Path Curvature
">IHstVhPthCrvt</span>
                      </td>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>15</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="number" name="value" required="required" value="0" min="0" max="32767">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="number" name="enum" min="0" style="width: 3em;">
                        </td>
                      </td>
                    </td>
                  </td>
                </td>
              </td>
            </td>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great. This works like a charm! Thank you. It also doesn't interact with the <form> is have around the table (not in the source code here).